# New York City and New York state Antique Gun Laws

Tags: new-york-state

Please excuse my unclear question that I posted before, but here is the revised question: Can you legally own an antique LONG ARM, for a personal collection because of its historic significance in NYC? (Given the fact that you don't have the intention to shoot it?)

Comment: Please spell out all acronyms at least once for the reference of future readers. All three letter acronyms stand for multiple different things.

Comment: Since when do you need guns in a Fantasy Football League?!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Trish I suspect that Federal Firearm Licensee is the intended acronym, but I'd rather not guess.